# Не работает CORS в nest js + react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, cors, nestjs

Всем привет. У меня есть сервер, который я писал на nest js, задеплоил на heroku при помощи docker контейнера(nest + postgres). Когда я делал запросы из postman или напрямую к серверу из браузера, все работал нормально. Но, сейчас я стал писать frontend и столкнулся с проблемой политики CORS. Я пытался добавлять `app.enableCors()` или `const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {cors: true});` и все другие их комбинации, даже пытался сделать `app.use(cors())`, как в express. Ничего не помогало. И я, просто, не знаю, что мне нужно делать в такой ситуации + времени на этот проект остается вообще немного. frontend я начал писать на react. Так же я пробовал передавать различные заголовки в сам запрос в react. Не знаю, надо ли отмечать, но небольшой сервер на express у меня работал корректно.

Вот как я делаю запрос при помощи axios.

```
const createInstance = (url = '') => axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://cp-itr.herokuapp.com/${url}`,
});
```

**Уточнение:**

Оказалось, что проблема не со всеми эндпоинтами. Ошибка CORS возникает только только на моем эндпоинте аутентификации oauth google, который я определил на сервере. Но, я все еще не знаю, как мне это исправить.

Моя старатегия google. В `callbackURL` содержится http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect (на localhost 3000 я запускаю react)

```
import {Strategy, Profile, VerifyCallback} from "passport-google-oauth20";

import {HelperService} from "../../helper/helper.service";


@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
    constructor(private helperService: HelperService) {
        super({
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
            scope: ['profile'],
            
        });
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback): Promise<any> {
        const payload = this.helperService.createAuthPayload(profile);

        done(null, payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, в общем, я смог найти ответ по данной проблеме. Он находится вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250525/google-login-with-passportstrategy-in-nestjs-backend-not-working-called-by-react . Если вкратце, то нужно перенести саму аутентификацию во фронт, а в бэк передавать только токен, который приходит нам после аутентификации, на тот эндпоинт, который проверит наш токен на валидность и уже дальше что-то с ним сделает.